# NFS network traffic with auto_direct

Tags: nfs

I'm interested in how the NFS network traffic goes when there is a redirect on the server side.

E.g.: the client accesses **dir_a** , mounted on the NFS **server_a**, but on **server_a** , **/etc/auto_direct** contains an entry that redirects **dir_a** to **dir_b** on **server_b**.

In this case, which server will the NFS client communicate with ? The most important question is, between which machines will the bulk of the NFS data traffic take place ?

All this is for Solaris 10, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some tests and from that it seems that the client somehow knows about the redirect:

```
user@client $ df dir_a
dir_a(auto_direct       ):       0 blocks        0 files
```

I've made some file access in **dir_a** and watched the interfaces of the client towards **server_a** and **server_b**.
On the client I did:

> cd dir_a; while true; do echo 1111111111111111111111111111 >> t; done

On the client's interface to **server_a** there was no traffic increase (only in the total traffic): (the time when the above script loop was running is marked with * below.)

```
nmsadm@atrcxb1951: netstat -I bnxe0 10
    input   bnxe0     output       input  (Total)    output
packets errs  packets errs  colls  packets errs  packets errs  colls 
8819    0     4476    0     0      8920    0     4494    0     0     
8800    0     4451    0     0      8871    0     4466    0     0     
8753    0     4371    0     0      27468   0     26777   0     0     *
8704    0     4378    0     0      27772   0     27227   0     0     *
8734    0     4381    0     0      28425   0     28044   0     0     *
8789    0     4453    0     0      13053   0     9317    0     0     
8765    0     4407    0     0      8871    0     4420    0     0
```

While on the client's interface towards **server_b** there was:

```
nmsadm@atrcxb1951:~$ netstat -I bnxe4 10
    input   bnxe4     output       input  (Total)    output
packets errs  packets errs  colls  packets errs  packets errs  colls 
121     0     17      0     0      8942    0     4494    0     0     
10467   0     12473   0     0      19264   0     16927   0     0     *
18579   0     22362   0     0      27291   0     26732   0     0     *
21735   0     25978   0     0      30466   0     30364   0     0     *
10971   0     12970   0     0      19760   0     17395   0     0     *
35      0     12      0     0      8782    0     4432    0     0
```

So in my case it seems that the client handles the redirection and **server_a** is not proxying the NFS data traffic.
I'd be still curious about under what circumstances does this work like this. Any configuration option, etc.